# Cannot find module ng2-bootstrap. Using JSPM, system.js, Visual Studio 2015 (Typescript HTML Project)

Tags: typescript, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular, jspm, systemjs

I'm trying to learn angular2, I followed few links
[for jspm and systemjs](http://html5hive.org/getting-started-with-angular-2/)
[for project type and settings](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1026938/AngularJS-Getting-Started-with-Visual-Studio)
[for .csproj configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30858164/cannot-find-external-module-angular2-angular2-angular2-w-typescript)

My understanding is that in angular2 application, the module part in the import statement : `import {} from 'module'` needs complete path to module file (it treats directory and file name as namespace).

Now, I'm using jspm and systemjs, which introduces a middle file config.js to map modules. I tried to understand its working but without any luck I got stuck with this error in 'hello.ts'.

```
Cannot find module 'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap'
```

### Here is my application set-up

IDE     : Visual Studio
Project : Typescript => Html Application with TypeScript

**Project Properties for Typescript**

[image: Using CommonJs module]

**Project.csproj**

```
</PropertyGroup>
    .
    .
    .
    <TypeScriptEmitDecoratorMetadata>True</TypeScriptEmitDecoratorMetadata>
    <TypeScriptExperimentalDecorators>True</TypeScriptExperimentalDecorators>
</PropertyGroup>
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "jspm": {
    "directories": {
      "baseURL": "app"
    },
    "dependencies": {
      "angular2": "npm:angular2@^2.0.0-alpha.45",
      "es6-shim": "github:es-shims/es6-shim@^0.33.9",
      "ng2-bootstrap": "npm:ng2-bootstrap@^0.44.6",
      "reflect-metadata": "npm:reflect-metadata@^0.1.2",
      "zone.js": "npm:zone.js@^0.5.8"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
      "typescript": "npm:typescript@^1.6.2"
    }
  }
}
```

**config.js**

```
System.config({
  baseURL: "/app",
  defaultJSExtensions: true,
  transpiler: "typescript",
  typescriptOptions: {
    "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "ES5",
      "module": "commonjs",
      "sourceMap": true,
      "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
      "experimentalDecorators": true,
      "removeComments": false,
      "noImplicitAny": false
    }
  },
  paths: {
    "github:*": "jspm_packages/github/*",
    "npm:*": "jspm_packages/npm/*"
  },

  packages: {
    "app": {
      "defaultExtension": "ts"
    }
  },

  map: {
    "angular2": "npm:angular2@2.0.0-alpha.45",
    "es6-shim": "github:es-shims/es6-shim@0.33.9",
    "ng2-bootstrap": "npm:ng2-bootstrap@0.44.6",
    "reflect-metadata": "npm:reflect-metadata@0.1.2",
    "typescript": "npm:typescript@1.6.2",
    "zone.js": "npm:zone.js@0.5.8",
    .
    .
    .
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Getting Started with Angular 2</title>
</head>
<body>
    <app></app>

    <script src="jspm_packages/system.js"></script>
    <script src="config.js"></script>
    <script>
        System.import('hello');
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**hello.ts**

```
/// <reference path="../typings/tsd.d.ts" /> 
import 'zone.js';
import 'reflect-metadata';
import 'es6-shim';
import {Component, View, bootstrap} from 'angular2/angular2';
import {Alert} from 'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap';

@Component({
    selector: 'app'
})
@View({
    template: `
        <div>Hello {{ name }}</div>
        <alert>Hi</alert>
    `
})
class App
{
    name: string = 'Sandeep';
}
bootstrap(App);
```

**tsd.d.ts**

```
/// <reference path="../app/jspm_packages/npm/angular2@2.0.0-alpha.45/bundles/typings/angular2/angular2.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="rx/rx-lite.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="rx/rx.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="angular2/angular2.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="es6-promise/es6-promise.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../app/jspm_packages/npm/ng2-bootstrap@0.44.6/ng2-bootstrap.d.ts" />
```

*PS: Application is working good without ng2-bootstrap*

Comment: I know this doesn't help you any, but it seems you got further than me? Perhaps you can help out on my question if you have a moment to spare?  http://stackoverflow.com/q/33473249/550975

Comment: Did you ever figure this out, I am having the same issue? I am pretty new to angular and typescript. I have set up the "5 minute Quickstart" application and built upon that. Now that I am trying to import my first module (ng2-bootstrap) it keeps looking in the src/ng2-bootstrap.

So far I have:
Used NPM to install bootstrap, and added the import on top of the TS file in question. How did you solve your issue?

Comment: @Wobbley No. So I just used css to get ahead. Waiting for stable version of angular 2.

Comment: Darn ok, thanks for the reply. I made a new question here, hoping to get some kind of answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34194792/importing-external-components-into-angular2-quickstart-project-with-typescript-a