# How can I get angular2 to work in Visual Studio 2015 with TypeScript?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, typescript, visual-studio-2015, angular

I am trying to get `Angular 2` to work in `Visual Studio 2015` with `Typescript`. I am trying to get the most basic example to work in an `MVC 5` type web project (`web.config` instead of `config.json`):

```
import {Component, bootstrap} from 'angular2/angular2';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: '<h1>My First Angular 2 App</h1>'
})
class AppComponent { }
bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

I'm trying the most minimal things needed to make this work. So I downloaded the most recent Angular 2 (alpha .45) and copied over all of the `TypeScript` in the  downloaded `modules` folder. Including all of the subfolders (**minus** the `docs` and `examples` ones.)

I am sure that this will work outside of `Visual Studio` as I have done this before, but I am trying to get it to work in `Visual Studio` and it is giving me over 3,000 errors and it looks like it is because I am missing other modules or something.

Here are a couple of the things I am missing:

**Map** (`default_keyvalue_differ.ts`, and many others):

```
export class DefaultKeyValueDiffer implements KeyValueDiffer {
  private _records: Map<any, any> = new Map();
```

**assert** (`lexer.ts`):

```
  scanCharacter(start: number, code: number): Token {
    assert(this.peek == code);
```

**Set** (command_compiler.ts):

```
function removeKeyValueArrayDuplicates(keyValueArray: string[]): string[] {
  var knownPairs = new Set();
```

**startsWith** (shadow_css.ts)

```
rule.selector.startsWith('@page')
```

**require** (parse5_adapter.ts)

```
var parse5 = require('parse5/index');
```

**@reactivex/rxjs/dist/cjs/Rx** (async.ts)

```
export {Subject} from '@reactivex/rxjs/dist/cjs/Rx';
```

There is much more than this. So my 1st question is, do I really need all of this stuff, or is some of it not required. 2nd and more importantly, how do I get `Visual Studio` to build my solution?

**Note**: I think this "very long example/tutorial" is what I was looking for except it's geared for MVC 6 (.NET Core) instead of MVC 5: http://chsakell.com/2016/01/01/cross-platform-single-page-applications-with-asp-net-5-angular-2-typescript/

Comment: I guess you have to install angular by npm or jspm. Reason is that, I tried to download Angular 2 (alpha .44) and also Angular 2 (alpha .45) using Visual Studio auto sync by package.json (npm) configurations but it was not able to successfully download it.

Comment: I used this command 'jspm install angular2 es6-shim reflect-metadata zone.js' from this link : http://html5hive.org/getting-started-with-angular-2/

And it was able to download angular alpha 45 with all dependencies. Give it a try

Comment: So that did get me the typings but now I have a new problem, I am getting a lot of `Duplicate identifier` errors, over 2,000 of them. I deleted all of the folders and ran npm install angular2 es6-shim reflect-metadata zone.js'' yhrn copied over the files into my solution folder finally, in `Visual Studio`, included the new folders in my project, and am now getting all of these errors :( This should not have to be so hard!

Comment: Try using angular2 quick start sample.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html

Comment: i've been struggling with alpha .44 & .45 in my typescript v 1.6.2, asp.net 5 for the past few days.  installing via npm worked but 3000+ typescript errors.  why is this so complicated!?  i'm about to meticulously go through each of the errors and deleting d.ts files.  i'd love to hear how anyone got this to work.

Comment: Don't delete just exclude node_modules from project

Comment: @SerjSagan, You have worked with vs13 with angulars or faced some issue on that? i am trying same but with vs15. I have faced 'module related'  issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know that SO isn't keen on pasting links to stuff, but this is a fairly large tutorial to follow, to just copy paste into here... and all bits of it are relevant to answer the question. Anyways, here's the tutorial provided by the Angular 2 team to get NG2 working in Visual Studio MVC 5:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/visual-studio-2015.html

Answer (score 14):

I suppose you have the problem with old `npm` version which uses Visual Studio 2015. I recommend you to open Output window of Visual Studio and to choose Show  output from "Bower/npm". You will see something like on the picture below:

[image]

The most imported line of the output is long and it's cut. I include it separetels:

> npm ERR! command "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\External\\node\node" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web
>   Tools\External\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install"

In other words, it's important to understand that Visual Studio 2015 uses some tools inclusive `npm` from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\External` directory. Angular2 have dependency package `reactivex/rxjs`, which require `"npm":"~2.0.0"`, but Visual Studio uses old `1.4.9` version instead (you can verify the `version` of `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\External\npm\node_modules\npm\package.json"`). Even if you would install the latest version of Nodejs and npm it will not help because Visual Studio 2015 will use the same old version of `npm`.

To fix the problem I suggest you to do the following:

- install the latest version of NodeJs. You can download it from https://nodejs.org/en/. If you would prefer to use x64-version then I recommend you to verify that you have already installed x86 in `C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs`. If x86-version exist, then uninstall it before starting installation of x64-version. After that you can install Nodejs. Today it would  be NodeJs 5.0.0 from `node-v5.0.0-x64.msi`.
- then you can start Command Prompt in admin mode (it's not mandotory) and use `npm update -g` to update `npm` or to use `npm install -g npm@latest` to install the latest version. I recommend you to use `npm -v` before and after the installation to verify that you install the latest version. Today it's version 3.3.12. Depend on how you installed/updated `npm` you can have it installed either in `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm` or in `%AppData%\npm` (the diretcory `C:\Users\Oleg\AppData\Roaming\npm` for example) or in both destinations.
- you should start text editor under administrator rights (Start menu, searching, type `notepad.exe` for example and press <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+Enter</kbd>). After that you should modify the file `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\External\npm.cmd` and set as the content something like `@"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "%AppData%\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" %*` or `@"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" %*`

After that you can just save `package.json` having the entry like  `"angular2": "^2.0.0-alpha.45"` in `"devDependencies"` or `"dependencies"` section and the installetion will be successful. You will probably see just the warning like

[image]

because you use now "too good" version of `npm`: the version 3.3.12 instead of some `2.x.x` version (based on the rule `"npm":"~2.0.0"` of the dependency package `reactivex/rxjs`).

P.S. Probably you have some other error messaged if you use MVC5 instead of prerelease version of MVC6 (ASP.NET 5), but the main problem is the same. You have to install new version of node and npm and modify `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\External\npm.cmd` to use the new version of npm.

Comment: You have worked with vs13 with angulars or faced some issue on that? i am trying same but with vs15. I have faced 'module related'  issue.

Comment: @NeerajSharma: I worked with Visual Studio 2015. The directory `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0` corresponds Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: Thank You! I've been searching for a solution 3 hours.

Comment: @David: You are welcome! I'm glad that the old answer is still helpful.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is for MVC6 (didn't saw that MVC5 is needed)

I recommend to use a **starter template**. I can recommend a template which also uses HMR and Angular Universal (server side rendering for SEO and faster page loads):

https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices

Get started:
http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2016/05/02/angular2-react-knockout-apps-on-aspnet-core/

Comment: Your answer is for `MVC 6`. This question is about `MVC 5`.

Comment: sorry, shall I delete?

Comment: I'd prefer you leave it as this answer may apply to someone who is looking into a similar but is needing MVC 6 info

Comment: Well, so nice of you to keep this alive. I am indeed in a situation that I want to use Angular2 with Asp.net MVC 6 (Core). However, I have already gone with the default template available in the MVC and started development. Now I want to include Angular2 using bower, but it is not available there. Could you please help. Thanks.

Comment: i recommend to use npm instead of bower

Answer (score -1):

i got it working.
npm install.  from the node_modules folder, remove all folders except angular2 and systemjs.  in the angular2 folder remove all except bundles.  in your bundles/typings folder remove all except angular2.
folder structure looks like this:

```
node_modules
  -- angular2
     -- bundles
        -- typings
           --angular2
  -- systemjs
```

Comment: I don't see a systemjs folder at all, nor was there an angular2 folder in my bundles/typings folder.  There's also a src folder in the angular2 folder that I am certain would cause problems were it to be removed.  How is your installation so different from mine?  I also used npm.  See [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33568723/visual-studio-typescript-project-with-a-node-package-raises-duplicate-identifier) for exactly the issue I'm having.