# WebStorm+Typescript: How to use without reference path?

Tags: typescript, webstorm

In Visual Studio, it's possible to use internal modules without having to include `/// <reference path="..." />` tags.
How can one accomplish the same in WebStorm 10?

Another question, how can I get WebStorm to import the typings to a project? WebStorm 10 puts typings in the cache folder.

Comment: If my answer helped you, please consider accepting it by clicking the ✔, or let me know what's missing.

Comment: accept the answer bro

Answer (score 23):

For **internal** modules, use a module loader such as [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org) / [SystemJS](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs) / [Webpack](http://webpack.github.io) / [Browserify](http://browserify.org), it will save you from having to write `/// <reference path="..." />` for **internal** modules and you will no longer need to use `module` *namespaces*.
If you use RequireJS, you need to run `tsc` with the argument `-m amd`, for Browserify `-m commonjs`, SystemJS & Webpack support both `amd` and `commonjs` styles (and others as well), however there's a simpler solution using [tsconfig.json](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/tsconfig.json) files (keep reading) where you don't have to add this *argument*.

For **external** *TypeScript* modules; usually *d.ts* files (Type Definitions for external JS libs, aka ***Typings***), install the [typings](https://nodejs.org) module via [Node](https://nodejs.org)'s package manager - [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com).
[typings](https://nodejs.org) helps you manage the *Typings* in your project, and combine all the `/// <reference path="..." />` lines into a single `d.ts` file.

For both internal and external modules, you can use a [tsconfig.json](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/tsconfig.json) file to eliminate the need for any `/// <reference path="..." />` lines.

[Webstorm 11](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/WI/WebStorm+11+EAP) (currently during development phase, distributed under an early-access-program, EAP) has built-in support for tsconfig.json files.
For Webstorm 10 you can use [this solution](https://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/465700;jsessionid=4E17E9ABA28D55378CDB8A43F53A8511).

If you choose not to use *tsconfig.json* while still using `typings` to manage your typings, and a module loader such as *RequireJS*, you would have to add the `-m [...]` *command line option*, and include a **single** line of `/// <reference path="path/typings/something.d.ts" />` on top of your internal *.ts* files, this .d.ts file will include all external *Typings* your project depends on.

---

### tsconfig.json

Put it in your project's root.
It's content might look something like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "experimentalDecorators": true
  },
  "files": [
    "typings/something.d.ts",
    "main.ts"
  ]
}
```

**Note** that you do not have to list out all of your `.ts` files under the `files:` key, `tsc` automatically knows it should include the dependencies (recursively) of any file mentioned under `files:`.

---

### Webstorm 11

Config *webstorm* to use `tsconfig.json`:
[image]

---

### tl;dr

If you can, it's best (IMHO) to do the following:

- Use a module loader (RequireJS/SystemJS/Browserify/Webpack).
- Manage your d.ts files (*typings*) with the `typings` module.
- Wrap it all in a *tsconfig.json* file (configure *webstorm* to use it).

After that, you can delete all of your `/// <reference path="..." />` lines.

Comment: @shatal That's not what I meant, you only have to include 2 typescript files in `tsconfig.json`: (1) the tsd.d.ts file (bundle of all typings), (2) your main typescript file (i.e main.ts). That's enough info for `tsc` to know that it should compile all dependencies of your main.ts file as well.

Comment: @shatal You can actually use relative paths :}, `tsc` knows how to handle these as well, both in `tsconfig.json` and for calls of `import` and `require` in your `.ts` files. See the example I've presented in `tsconfig.json`.

Comment: @shatal For gulp you can use [gulp-tsc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-tsc) or [gulp-typescript](https://github.com/ivogabe/gulp-typescript).
Keep in mind, for such a trivial task like transpiling typescript files to js: Once you configure tsconfig.json, you can simply run `tsc` and that's it. if you use web storm, it does it automatically for you, no need to run anything. if you are working without webstorm, you can run `tsc -w` which will run and compile on the go, monitoring live changes.

Comment: Since tsd is deprecated (even the officially site is down) I want to state that typings is working very well with the latest WebStorm version (2016.2.3).In fact just after installing a local library (in my case lodash) I can easily use it in my typescript code.Pressing alt + enter on my mac after using a lodash function , webstorm added the following line to my app.ts : import _ = require("lodash");

Comment: @skiabox Thanks, updated accordingly. `typings` is definitely more common than `tsd` now.